# Database connection using dplyr with date field in database

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

Is there some magic to using `dplyr` to access a database when it has a date field?

A `dplyr` `tbl_df` converts mysql datetime fields to chr.  That wouldn't be so bad if I could `as.Date()` them back.  But if I do that before `collect()`'ing the table, I get an error that `as.Date()` is an invalid sql function.  I can sort-of workaround this by calling `collect()`, but then I'm copying all of the data out of the database, which is what I was trying to avoid.  In addition, once I've `collect()`'ed, its a `data.frame`, so if I want to join it with another `tbl` I have to set `copy=TRUE` and copy that one into memory as well.

Comment: dplyr doesn't do any conversion, it relies on the underlying database connector. If you provide a reproducible example, it would be possible to see which one you're using

Comment: RMySql - thanks Hadley, you answered it.

Comment: Hi, what did you do? I'm having a similar problem, but didn't understand what was the solution.

Comment: This is till out here unanswered... @hadley if you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importing date correctly from MySQL into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762009/importing-date-correctly-from-mysql-into-r)