# importing date correctly from MySQL into R

Tags: r, dplyr, rmysql

My question is pretty much the same [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597932/databse-connection-using-dplyr-with-date-field-in-databse). In short, I'm using dplyr (along with RMySQL) to import a MySQL table with a datetime column, and I want to convert it to date in R. In the question linked above, no answer was posted, only a comment by Hadley. The OP apparently found a solution based on the comment made. I understood from Hadley's comment that I could solve the issue by properly importing the column as date into R. Then there would be no need to use as.Date. However, I couldn't find how to do that with dplyr and RMySQL.

I don't know how to post a fully reproducible example, because it's a MySQL database connection, but I'll post my code:

If I try:

```
pedidos <-  my_db %>%
tbl("pedidos") %>%
mutate(test = as.Date(DateSent))
```

And then I run:

```
pedidos
```

R returns:

```
FUNCTION AS.DATE does not exist
```

Like the OP in the other question, I can workaround the issue using collect(), but then it defeats the purpose of not copying the data into memory. Here´s some info about data type in MySQL
DateSent is datetime

and R sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RMySQL_0.10.11 DBI_0.5-1      dplyr_0.5.0   
[4] digest_0.6.12 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0      
[4] assertthat_0.1 rsconnect_0.5  tools_3.3.1   
[7] tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.8
```

Comment: What's the schema of the table you are trying to access? You can't call R functions that don't have equivalents in your data.base without out calling collect. If dplyr can't translate your mutate request into a proper SQL statement, then it can't be run without pulling the data into R.

Comment: Yep, That's my understanding. And that's why I think the solution is to import the column in the correct format. Regarding the schema, the table has a lot of columns. But the relevant column info is: field: DateSent; type: datetime; Null: yes; Default: NULL

Comment: Maybe try RMySQL_0.11 or newer, [they claim to support proper datetime values](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/blob/2128ad61bb2d2503e105c4daeaa96a69b7bac888/NEWS.md#rmysql-011-1-2016-03-24)

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've coped with the datetime column problem as well, however a short answer to say, replace your current MySQL DBI Driver with [RMariaDB](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB) is the solution.

As the comments mentioned under this question, this problem has actually solved in the development upstream of [RMySQL from 0.11](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/blob/2128ad61bb2d2503e105c4daeaa96a69b7bac888/NEWS.md#rmysql-011-1-2016-03-24), but the only problem is this version is not available from official CRAN repository. In another words, If you don't mind installing a package manually through devtools, installation from the RMySQL 0.11 source code is exactly an answer for this question.

But as stated officially in the readme, [RMariaDB](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/commit/4ee512c9579e2a9b58d3ef2c8c68fc744d6670bb#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R4) package is going to be as a replacement to the RMySQL driver. Surely, the function that [Datetime Support](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/blob/master/NEWS.md#rmariadb-011-1-2016-03-24) is also included in the mainstream of RMariaDB package. What's more, the newest release of Version 1.0.6 is available from CRAN official repository.